# Report: Cased Actively Open during any given Month

Tags: salesforce, report

I need to create a report that shows multiple years by month and if a case was open at any given time during the month.

So if a Case was Created on 1/1/24 and Closed on 3/15/24 it would count towards the months of January, Febuary, and March as being open.

I feel like this should be possible, but it's Friday and my brain is fried...

Jan. |  Feb. | Mar. | Apr. | May | Jun.
45.  |  39.  |  48. |  67. |  34.|  43.

IF {Column Date} is < CreatedDate and > ClosedDate Then Count as 'True'

Looking at Summary fields and idk... blah...